# Tree Conflict Error GIT Repository Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, tree, branch, source-control-explorer

I am using Xcode and am trying to merge branches. I am receiving the "tree conflicts" error and do not understand the problem. I somehow have a branch with multiple versions. Ex. MainBranch1, MainBranch2, MainBranch3

Comment: If you are familiar with using git from the command line, it might be helpful to drop out to the console and do a git status in the repository folder. This will give you more and better information and often includes instructions on how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try opening terminal and performing a git status command, make sure you change directory to the appropriate file location. Then either add or remove the conflicting branches.